# Make bucket available by domain.com

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have created a bucket available by www.domain.com, but I want make it available by domain.com.

It is impossible to make CNAME record for domain.com pointing to c.storage.googleapis.com so that it is impossible to create bucket with name domain.com.

How could I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that it is possible by setting preferred domain in Google Webmaster Tools for site **www.domain.com** to **domain.com**.

[Google documentation](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/44231)